# shuffling/permutating a DataFrame in pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

What's a simple and efficient way to shuffle a dataframe in pandas, by rows or by columns? I.e. how to write a function `shuffle(df, n, axis=0)` that takes a dataframe, a number of shuffles `n`, and an axis (`axis=0` is rows, `axis=1` is columns) and returns a copy of the dataframe that has been shuffled `n` times.

**Edit**: key is to do this without destroying the row/column labels of the dataframe. If you just shuffle `df.index` that loses all that information. I want the resulting `df` to be the same as the original except with the order of rows or order of columns different.

**Edit2**: My question was unclear. When I say shuffle the rows, I mean shuffle each row independently. So if you have two columns `a` and `b`, I want each row shuffled on its own, so that you don't have the same associations between `a` and `b` as you do if you just re-order each row as a whole. Something like:

```
for 1...n:
  for each col in df: shuffle column
return new_df
```

But hopefully more efficient than naive looping. This does not work for me:

```
def shuffle(df, n, axis=0):
        shuffled_df = df.copy()
        for k in range(n):
            shuffled_df.apply(np.random.shuffle(shuffled_df.values),axis=axis)
        return shuffled_df

df = pandas.DataFrame({'A':range(10), 'B':range(10)})
shuffle(df, 5)
```

Comment: [See this simple pandas solution below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47112434/3707607)

Comment: ^ Your answer does answer the question but it seems is not the answer people are looking for

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
In [16]: def shuffle(df, n=1, axis=0):     
    ...:     df = df.copy()
    ...:     for _ in range(n):
    ...:         df.apply(np.random.shuffle, axis=axis)
    ...:     return df
    ...:     

In [17]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A':range(10), 'B':range(10)})

In [18]: shuffle(df)

In [19]: df
Out[19]: 
   A  B
0  8  5
1  1  7
2  7  3
3  6  2
4  3  4
5  0  1
6  9  0
7  4  6
8  2  8
9  5  9
```

Comment: How do I distinguish rows from column shuffling here?

Comment: Thanks.. I clarified my question which was unclear. I am looking to shuffle by row independently of other rows - so shuffle in such a way that you don't always have `1,5` together and `4,8` together (but also not just a column shuffle which limits you to two choices)

Comment: **warning** I thought ``df.apply(np.random.permutation)`` would work as the solution ``df.reindex(np.random.permutation(df.index))`` and looked neater, but actually they behave differently. The latter maintains association between columns of the same row, the former doesn't. My misunderstanding, of course, but hopefully it will save other people from the same mistake.

Comment: What is 'np' in this context?

Comment: numpy. It's common to do:
`import numpy as np`

Comment: @root What does "n" in the data stands for? Can we change it to other values, what is the max value?

Comment: It seems like `n` is "how many times do you want to shuffle?"  In that case, shuffling more than once doesn't make much sense (unless you think the rng is suspect).

Comment: I only wanted to do one shuffle so I just used `df.apply(np.random.shuffle, index=1)` but this doesn't seem to do anything, printing the resulting df looks exactly the same as the input. If I do `df = df.apply( ... )` I get a Series with `Nans.` If I do `df.apply( ... inplace=True)` then I get an error.

Answer (score 230):

Use numpy's `random.permuation` function:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A':range(10), 'B':range(10)})

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
   A  B
0  0  0
1  1  1
2  2  2
3  3  3
4  4  4
5  5  5
6  6  6
7  7  7
8  8  8
9  9  9


In [3]: df.reindex(np.random.permutation(df.index))
Out[3]:
   A  B
0  0  0
5  5  5
6  6  6
3  3  3
8  8  8
7  7  7
9  9  9
1  1  1
2  2  2
4  4  4
```

Comment: +1 because this is exactly what I was looking for (even though it turns out it's not what the OP wanted)

Comment: Also can use `df.iloc[np.random.permutation(np.arange(len(df)))]` if there's dupes and stuff (and may be faster for mi).

Comment: Nice method. Is there a way to do it in-place though?

Comment: For me (Python v3.6 and Pandas v0.20.1) I had to replace `df.reindex(np.random.permutation(df.index))` by `df.set_index(np.random.permutation(df.index))` to get the desired effect.

Comment: after `set_index` like Emanuel, I also needed `df.sort_index(inplace=True)`

Comment: This does not work anymore. Running python 3.6.5, numpy 1.15.0, pandas 0.23.3, the only solution that worked was Andy Hayden's one : `df.iloc[np.random.permutation(np.arange(len(df)))]`

Answer (score 99):

Sampling randomizes, so just sample the entire data frame.

```
df.sample(frac=1)
```

As @Corey Levinson notes, you have to be careful when you reassign:

```
df['column'] = df['column'].sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Note if you are trying to reassign a column using this, you have to do `df['column'] = df['column'].sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)`

Answer (score 23):

You can use  [`sklearn.utils.shuffle()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.shuffle.html) ([requires](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4008) sklearn 0.16.1 or higher to support Pandas data frames):

```
# Generate data
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':range(5), 'B':range(5)})
print('df: {0}'.format(df))

# Shuffle Pandas data frame
import sklearn.utils
df = sklearn.utils.shuffle(df)
print('\n\ndf: {0}'.format(df))
```

outputs:

```
df:    A  B
0  0  0
1  1  1
2  2  2
3  3  3
4  4  4


df:    A  B
1  1  1
0  0  0
3  3  3
4  4  4
2  2  2
```

Then you can use [`df.reset_index()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to reset the index column, if needs to be:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print('\n\ndf: {0}'.format(df)
```

outputs:

```
df:    A  B
0  1  1
1  0  0
2  4  4
3  2  2
4  3  3
```

Comment: FYI, `df.sample(frac=1)` is marginally faster (76.9 vs 78.9 ms for 400k rows).

Answer (score 11):

A simple solution in pandas is to use the `sample` method independently on each column. Use `apply` to iterate over each column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 'b':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})
df

   a  b
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  3  3
3  4  4
4  5  5
5  6  6

df.apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=1).values)

   a  b
0  4  2
1  1  6
2  6  5
3  5  3
4  2  4
5  3  1
```

You must use `.value` so that you return a numpy array and not a Series, or else the returned Series will align to the original DataFrame not changing a thing:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=1))

   a  b
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  3  3
3  4  4
4  5  5
5  6  6
```

Comment: Thanks @Ted Exactly why I came here. Spot on!

Comment: I shuffled a single column by doing `np.random.shuffle(df['b'].values)` . Take note that [`np.random.shuffle()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html) modifies your dataframe in-place.

Answer (score 6):

From the docs use `sample()`:

```
In [79]: s = pd.Series([0,1,2,3,4,5])

# When no arguments are passed, returns 1 row.
In [80]: s.sample()
Out[80]: 
0    0
dtype: int64

# One may specify either a number of rows:
In [81]: s.sample(n=3)
Out[81]: 
5    5
2    2
4    4
dtype: int64

# Or a fraction of the rows:
In [82]: s.sample(frac=0.5)
Out[82]: 
5    5
4    4
1    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 4):

I resorted to adapting @root 's answer slightly and using the raw values directly. Of course, this means you lose the ability to do fancy indexing but it works perfectly for just shuffling the data.

```python
In [1]: import numpy

In [2]: import pandas

In [3]: df = pandas.DataFrame({"A": range(10), "B": range(10)})    

In [4]: %timeit df.apply(numpy.random.shuffle, axis=0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 406 µs per loop

In [5]: %%timeit
   ...: for view in numpy.rollaxis(df.values, 1):
   ...:     numpy.random.shuffle(view)
   ...: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 22.8 µs per loop

In [6]: %timeit df.apply(numpy.random.shuffle, axis=1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 746 µs per loop

In [7]: %%timeit                                      
for view in numpy.rollaxis(df.values, 0):
    numpy.random.shuffle(view)
   ...: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 23.4 µs per loop
```

Note that `numpy.rollaxis` brings the specified axis to the first dimension and then let's us iterate over arrays with the remaining dimensions, i.e., if we want to shuffle along the first dimension (columns), we need to roll the second dimension to the front, so that we apply the shuffling to views over the first dimension.

```
In [8]: numpy.rollaxis(df, 0).shape
Out[8]: (10, 2) # we can iterate over 10 arrays with shape (2,) (rows)

In [9]: numpy.rollaxis(df, 1).shape
Out[9]: (2, 10) # we can iterate over 2 arrays with shape (10,) (columns)
```

Your final function then uses a trick to bring the result in line with the expectation for applying a function to an axis:

```python
def shuffle(df, n=1, axis=0):     
    df = df.copy()
    axis = int(not axis) # pandas.DataFrame is always 2D
    for _ in range(n):
        for view in numpy.rollaxis(df.values, axis):
            numpy.random.shuffle(view)
    return df
```

Answer (score 3):

This might be more useful when you want your index shuffled.

```
def shuffle(df):
    index = list(df.index)
    random.shuffle(index)
    df = df.ix[index]
    df.reset_index()
    return df
```

It selects new df using new index, then reset them.

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is for a `pandas` df but in the case the shuffle occurs by row (column order changed, row order unchanged), then the columns names do not matter anymore and it could be interesting to use an `np.array` instead, then `np.apply_along_axis()` will be what you are looking for.

If that is acceptable then this would be helpful, note it is easy to switch the axis along which the data is shuffled.

If you panda data frame is named `df`, maybe you can:

1. get the values of the dataframe with `values = df.values`,
2. create an `np.array` from `values`
3. apply the method shown below to shuffle the `np.array` by row or column
4. recreate a new (shuffled) pandas df from the shuffled `np.array`

#### Original array

```
a = np.array([[10, 11, 12], [20, 21, 22], [30, 31, 32],[40, 41, 42]])
print(a)
[[10 11 12]
 [20 21 22]
 [30 31 32]
 [40 41 42]]
```

#### Keep row order, shuffle colums within each row

```
print(np.apply_along_axis(np.random.permutation, 1, a))
[[11 12 10]
 [22 21 20]
 [31 30 32]
 [40 41 42]]
```

#### Keep colums order, shuffle rows within each column

```
print(np.apply_along_axis(np.random.permutation, 0, a))
[[40 41 32]
 [20 31 42]
 [10 11 12]
 [30 21 22]]
```

#### Original array is unchanged

```
print(a)
[[10 11 12]
 [20 21 22]
 [30 31 32]
 [40 41 42]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work around I found if you want to only shuffle a subset of the DataFrame:

```
shuffle_to_index = 20
df = pd.concat([df.iloc[np.random.permutation(range(shuffle_to_index))], df.iloc[shuffle_to_index:]])
```