# Row flagging in Python

Tags: python, pandas, flags

I am reading data from a text file and then I do a sort of random walk among the rows. How would you mark a row as "read"?

This is how I'm reading the data:

```
import pandas as pd
set = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep=" ", header = None)
set.columns = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shuffle the dataframe with numpy using the technique in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772009/shuffling-permutation-a-dataframe-in-pandas), then iterate over the rows.

so:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep=" ", header = None)
df.columns = columns = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]
df = df.apply(numpy.random.permutation)

for row in df.iterrows():
    #process row here
```

Comment: Thanks bananafish. What I'm doing is not exactly a random walk: each row describes the position of a point on a plane, and I need to group the points finding the curve they are part of. My plan is to a) starting from the first line, search for the closest point which could be part of the curve; b) flag the line corresponding to the point just found.

Comment: Oh. In that case, maybe add another column that you flag as true/false depending on whether you've processed it?

Answer (score 0):

To add a column: `data.insert(8, "flag", 0)`. 0 can be changed to 1 or other values later in the code