# Sampling a dataframe based on a given distribution

Tags: python, pandas, graphlab, sframe

How can I sample a pandas dataframe or graphlab sframe based on a  given  class\label distribution values eg: I want to sample an data frame having a label\class column to select rows such that each class label is equally fetched thereby having a similar frequency for each class label corresponding to a uniform distribution of class labels . Or best would be to get samples according to the class distribution we want.

```
+------+-------+-------+
| col1 | clol2 | class |
+------+-------+-------+
| 4    | 45    | A     |
+------+-------+-------+
| 5    | 66    | B     |
+------+-------+-------+
| 5    | 6     | C     |
+------+-------+-------+
| 4    | 6     | C     |
+------+-------+-------+
| 321  | 1     | A     |
+------+-------+-------+
| 32   | 432   | B     |
+------+-------+-------+
| 5    | 3     | B     |
+------+-------+-------+

given a huge dataframe like above and the required frequency distribution like below:
+-------+--------------+
| class | nostoextract |
+-------+--------------+
| A     | 2            |
+-------+--------------+
| B     | 2            |
+-------+--------------+
| C     | 2            |
+-------+--------------+
```

The above should extract rows from the first dataframe based on the given frequency distribution in the second frame where the frequency count values are given in nostoextract column to give a sampled frame where each class appears at max 2 times. should ignore and continue if cant find sufficient classes to meet the required count. The resulting dataframe is to be used for a decision tree based classifier.

As a commentator puts it the sampled dataframe has to contain nostoextract different instances of the corresponding class? Unless there are not enough examples for a given class in which case you just take all the available ones.

Comment: Could you add some examples of what you want to achieve? And did you look at  `pandas.DataFrame.sample`? (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html)

Comment: @chris-sc yes it does not allow to sample based on class column

Comment: basically I want to sample a skewed data frame such that all the class labels are sufficiently represented as much as possible. The class labels are in the "label" column. This is fed to a classifier. @chris-sc

Comment: I think you want [`StratifiedKFold`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedKFold.html#sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedKFold) this returns iterators that preserve a uniform split of your data for each class label

Comment: @EdChum No it does not give an option to specify the class distribution, and does not do what is asked. It just samples preserving existing distribution to the new samples.

Comment: Sorry can you post example code and desired output as I don't quite get what you want

Comment: @EdChum posted an example , do let me know any more doubts

Comment: So are you wanting just the same number of samples for each label? For instance in your example although you have 3 'Bs' you end up with 2 of each class?

Comment: So you basically want to bootstrap, where each bootstrap sample has to contain `nostoextract` different instances of the corresponding class? Unless there are not enough examples for a given class in which case you just take all the available ones?

Comment: @swenzel yes you are right

Answer (score 5):

Can you split your first dataframe into class-specific sub-dataframes, and then sample at will from those?

i.e.

```
dfa = df[df['class']=='A']
dfb = df[df['class']=='B']
dfc = df[df['class']=='C']
....
```

Then once you've split/created/filtered on dfa, dfb, dfc, pick a number from the top as desired (if dataframes don't have any particular sort-pattern)

```
 dfasamplefive = dfa[:5]
```

Or use the sample method as described by a previous commenter to directly take a random sample:

```
dfasamplefive = dfa.sample(n=5)
```

If that suits your needs, all that's left to do is automate the process, feeding in the number to be sampled from the control dataframe you have as your second dataframe containing the desired number of samples.

Comment: Yes, you're quite right, thanks for that! [edited accordingly]

Answer (score 4):

I think this will solve your problem:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'cols1':[4, 5, 5, 4, 321, 32, 5],
                     'clol2':[45, 66, 6, 6, 1, 432, 3],
                     'class':['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B']})

freq = pd.DataFrame({'class':['A', 'B', 'C'],
                     'nostoextract':[2, 2, 2], })

def bootstrap(data, freq):
    freq = freq.set_index('class')

    # This function will be applied on each group of instances of the same
    # class in `data`.
    def sampleClass(classgroup):
        cls = classgroup['class'].iloc[0]
        nDesired = freq.nostoextract[cls]
        nRows = len(classgroup)

        nSamples = min(nRows, nDesired)
        return classgroup.sample(nSamples)

    samples = data.groupby('class').apply(sampleClass)

    # If you want a new index with ascending values
    # samples.index = range(len(samples))

    # If you want an index which is equal to the row in `data` where the sample
    # came from
    samples.index = samples.index.get_level_values(1)

    # If you don't change it then you'll have a multiindex with level 0
    # being the class and level 1 being the row in `data` where
    # the sample came from.

    return samples

print(bootstrap(data,freq))
```

Prints:

```
  class  clol2  cols1
0     A     45      4
4     A      1    321
1     B     66      5
5     B    432     32
3     C      6      4
2     C      6      5
```

If you don't want the result to be ordered by classes, you can [permute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15772330/2677943) it in the end.

Comment: thanks can the same be done for an sframe? (graphlab

Comment: @stackit, dunno... they seem to have the same interface. Did you try it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution for SFrames. It's not *exactly* what you want, because it samples points randomly, so that the results don't necessarily have precisely the number of rows you specify. An exact method would probably shuffle the data randomly then take the first `k` rows for a given class, but this gets you pretty darn close.

```
import random
import graphlab as gl

## Construct data.
sf = gl.SFrame({'col1': [4, 5, 5, 4, 321, 32, 5],
                'col2': [45, 66, 6, 6, 1, 432, 3],
                'class': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B']})

freq = gl.SFrame({'class': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                  'number': [3, 1, 0]})

## Count how many instances of each class and compute a sampling
#  probability.
grp = sf.groupby('class', gl.aggregate.COUNT)
freq = freq.join(grp, on ='class', how='left')
freq['prob'] = freq.apply(lambda x: float(x['number']) / x['Count'])

## Join the sampling probability back to the original data.
sf = sf.join(freq[['class', 'prob']], on='class', how='left')

## Sample the original data, then subset.
sf['sample_mask'] = sf.apply(lambda x: 1 if random.random() <= x['prob'] 
                             else 0)
sf2 = sf[sf['sample_mask'] == 1]
```

In my sample run, I happened to get the exact number of samples I specified, but again, this is not guaranteed with this solution.

```
>>> sf2
+-------+------+------+
| class | col1 | col2 |
+-------+------+------+
|   A   |  4   |  45  |
|   A   | 321  |  1   |
|   B   |  32  | 432  |
+-------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got a clean solution.

Lets setup `df`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'cols1':[4, 5, 5, 4, 321, 32, 5],
                   'clol2':[45, 66, 6, 6, 1, 432, 3],
                   'class':['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B']})
```

---

### One-liner:

An even distribution can be achieved with one-liner:

`df.groupby('class', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.sample(2))`

---

### With specified distribution:

If you want to specify the distribution, you need to modify it a little bit:

```py
freq = {'A':1,'B':2,'C':3}

def get_sample(df,freq):
    sample_size = freq[df['class'].iloc[0]]
    return df.sample(sample_size, replace=True)

df.groupby('class', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: get_sample(x,freq))
```

`replace=True` allows you to oversample a class.