# Python/Pandas - partitioning a pandas DataFrame in 10 disjoint, equally-sized subsets

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, partitioning

I want to partition a pandas DataFrame into ten disjoint, equally-sized, randomly composed subsets.

I know I can randomly sample one tenth of the original pandas DataFrame using:

```
partition_1 = pandas.DataFrame.sample(frac=(1/10))
```

However, how can I obtain the other nine partitions? If I'd do `pandas.DataFrame.sample(frac=(1/10))` again, there exists the possibility that my subsets are not disjoint.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This already has been answered: just combine [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17315875/2077270) with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15772356/2077270)

Answer (score 4):

Starting with this.

```
 dfm = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',  'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo']*2,
                      'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'two', 'two', 'one', 'three']*2}) 

     A      B
0   foo    one
1   bar    one
2   foo    two
3   bar  three
4   foo    two
5   bar    two
6   foo    one
7   foo  three
8   foo    one
9   bar    one
10  foo    two
11  bar  three
12  foo    two
13  bar    two
14  foo    one
15  foo  three

Usage: 
Change "4" to "10", use [i] to get the slices.  

np.random.seed(32) # for reproducible results.
np.array_split(dfm.reindex(np.random.permutation(dfm.index)),4)[1]
      A    B
2   foo  two
5   bar  two
10  foo  two
12  foo  two

np.array_split(dfm.reindex(np.random.permutation(dfm.index)),4)[3]

     A      B
13  foo    two
11  bar  three
0   foo    one
7   foo  three
```

Answer (score 3):

Say `df` is your dataframe, and you want `N_PARTITIONS` partitions of roughly equal size (they will be of *exactly* equal size if `len(df)` is divisible by `N_PARTITIONS`).

Use `np.random.permutation` to permute the array `np.arange(len(df))`. Then take slices of that array with step `N_PARTITIONS`, and extract the corresponding rows of your dataframe with `.iloc[]`.

```
import numpy as np

permuted_indices = np.random.permutation(len(df))

dfs = []
for i in range(N_PARTITIONS):
    dfs.append(df.iloc[permuted_indices[i::N_PARTITIONS]])
```

Since you are on Python 2.7, it might be better to switch `range(N_PARTITIONS)` by `xrange(N_PARTITIONS)` to get an iterator instead of a list.

Answer (score 2):

use `np.random.permutations` :

`df.loc[np.random.permutation(df.index)]`

it will shuffle the dataframe and keep column names, after  you could split the dataframe into 10.